# Auto-unboxing in Scala pattern-match

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, unboxing

In the following code, I am getting a compilation error stating that I have a type mismatch on 'x':

```
val someRef: java.lang.Long = 42L
someRef match {
  case x: Long => println("The answer: " + x)
  case _ => println("Unknown")
}
```

How do I get Scala to auto-unbox someRef in the match statement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The type system doesn't know about boxing at this level.  But it does know that if there is an `Any`, a boxed `Long` is really (presumably) supposed to be just a `Long` (from the `AnyVal` part of the class inheritance tree).  So:

```
val someRef: java.lang.Long = 42L
(someRef: Any) match {
  case x : Long => println("The answer is " + x)
  case _ => println("What answer?")
}
```